# Confused with angular tutorial step

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-mock

From https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11 unit test section:

```
it('should create "phones" model with 2 phones fetched from xhr', function() {
    expect(scope.phones).toEqualData([]);
    $httpBackend.flush();

    expect(scope.phones).toEqualData([{name: 'Nexus S'}, {name: 'Motorola DROID'}]);
});
```

I just dont get the point why line 2 is evaluating to true and `scope.phones` is getting `[]` after

```
scope = $rootScope.$new();
ctrl = $controller(PhoneListCtrl, {$scope: scope});
```

Before `ctrl = $controller(PhoneListCtrl, {$scope: scope});` 
`scope.phones` evaluates to `undefined` and right after but before `$httpBackend.flush()`, it evaluates to an empty array, can anybody explain the mystery, please?

Comment: I think it is because `ctrl = $controller(...)` instantiates `PhoneListCtrl` controller, and runs `$scope.phones = Phone.query();` which is probably expected to return an array (`isArray:true`).

Comment: @nrodic but why is it returning []??? It's supposed to be undefined until we fire up actual $httpBackend.flush() and fill it with an array.

Comment: It is resource factory and in controller debugger shows object inheriting from Array (because of `isArray=true`), also containing $promise object. After `httpBackend.flush()` array populates with data "returned from service". I think. See about `isArray` parameter [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

Comment: @nrodic if you look further down the same page, you'll see `expect(scope.phone).toEqualData({});` right in the section of PhoneDetailCtrl. How would you explain that with this logic?

Comment: `$resource` documentation referenced in my previous comment, under Returns heading shows default `isArray` values, where `get` method defaults to object (and interestingly, `query` defaults to array thus making `isArray=true` redundant). `get` method is used by `PhoneDetailController` initializer when setting `$scope.phone`. I really think that's all of the mystery.

Comment: @nrodic but it still doesnt make it 100% clear for me the part that concerns variable assignment, I mean when we instantiate the PhoneListCtrl in test, at that moment we havent yet fired the fake http request, and all we got is the assignment with $scope.phones = [PROMISE], but in test we are testing the === equality to an empty array, sry but im totly confused. :(

Comment: Shouldn't be `===`. Reading more carefully section Test in tutorial, step 11, it says: "If we were to use the standard toEqual matcher, our tests would fail because the test values would not match the responses exactly. To solve the problem, we use a newly-defined toEqualData Jasmine matcher. When the toEqualData matcher compares two objects, it takes only object properties into account and ignores methods." Don't forget that $resource object defaults either to [] or {} before it gets populated. Hope your curiosity is satisfied now :) Also, great question, indeed. I learned a lot.

Comment: @nrodic Absolutely awesome answer, now I get it, thank you!